# How to place output from an external php file to a specific place on the page

Tags: php, html, css

I have looked at other posts here regarding similar questions but cannot find an answer.

**Edit** I have been playing with this and I want to alter my question somewhat.

I am having a problem placing the output that is echoed from an external php file.

Here is some example code to demonstrate my problem - this is my main file `writephp.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test Php </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="writephp.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="allContent">    
        <?php for($i=0; $i<3; $i++): ?>
            <div class="commentBox">
               <p> Just a box</p>
            </div>  
        <?php endfor; ?>
        <a href="write.php?outputHtml">Php output</a>       
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Now I can center this with css:

```
.allContent {
width: 400px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
font-family: Arial;
}
.commentBox {
border: 1px solid black;
width: 400px;
padding: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
margin-top: 5px;
}
```

So in the html file the php writes out boxes which are centered in the page since the php loop is within the "allConent" div.

The anchor envokes an external php file which will echo some more boxes.

That file looks like this and is called `write.php` (`writephp.php` is the main file this is called from):

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['outputHtml']))
{
 echo "<p  class='allContent commentBox'>" . "This is from external PHP" . "</p>";
 echo "<p  class='allContent commentBox'>" . "This is also from external PHP" . "</p>";
 include 'writephp.php';
}
```

[image: output looks like]

But the echoed output from the external php is above the output from the main file  -in fact it is placed before the `<!doctype html>` tag , obviously not good.

the page source looks like this:

```
<p  class='commentBox allContent'>This is from external PHP</p
><p class='allContent commentBox'>This is also from  external PHP</p>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test Php </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="writephp.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="allContent">    
                        <div class="commentBox">
               <p> Just a box</p>
            </div>  
                        <div class="commentBox">
               <p> Just a box</p>
            </div>  
                        <div class="commentBox">
               <p> Just a box</p>
            </div>  
        <a href="write.php?outputHtml">Php output</a>       
    </div>  
</body>
```

In general my question would be "**how do I place html coming from an external php file anywhere I want on the page?** "

Comment: **You can never have multiple elements with the same id on a single HTML page**. How exactly are you loading the new content?

Comment: the external php file uses `include 'writephp.php'` which is the main page. It works but I know I should not have multiple elements with the same id which is why I am wondering what the proper way to do this is.

Comment: what is writephp.php?

Comment: sorry I didn't make that clear writephp.php is my poorly named main file. It is the top file I listed here that is my html and php code.

Comment: The `id` attribute value is **unique**. Therefor, giving the same `id` value to two elements invalidates your web page towards W3C recommendations.

Comment: Yes I understand that, which is why I am trying to find out the proper way to do this. I can't have two classes in my element so even if I changed "allContent" to a class rather than an id it would still not allow me to pick up the styling from two places.

Comment: @user2250892 that's what I thought.. I don't think you're approaching this the right way, what is the goal here? you want to append boxes to your main page? if so then look for an ajax solution, right now your write.php is echoing the two boxes and then after it is outputting all the content from the main page including <!DOCTYPE> <head> etc., that's not valid

Comment: I am just trying to get all the content centered.

Comment: but why are you including the main file in write.php?

Comment: so that the echoed output goes there. I want all output from both sources - the main file and the external file - to be on the same page.

Comment: Why can't you have two classes on the same element?

Comment: I tried that but it only picked up the styling from the first class listed. The second class was ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['outputHtml']))
{
 echo "<p  class='commentBox'>" . "This is from external PHP" . "</p>";
 echo "<p  class='commentBox'>" . "This is also from external PHP" . "</p>";
 include 'writephp.php';
}
```

This in your write.php is not correct, see `writephp.php` is a complete HTML page with `<html>` `<head>` and `<body>` tags and you are including it after echoing some `<p>` tags, that won't make your new boxes appear magically inside the body of the page, you would be creating some invalid markup with the two `<p>` at the beginning of the file followed by the `<!DOCTYPE><html>` etc...

**EDIT**

Regarding the update to your question that now reads **"How place output from an external php file to a specific place on the page"**

As @Robert Seddon-Smith correctly noted in his answer, using `include` will make the content appear exactly at the point when the call is made, so if you wanted to include your new boxes in your main file then the call to `include` should be backwards, that is, you should include the content inside the main file, you can use this example to test it:

Modify `write.php` to just echo the boxes when the $_GET variable is present

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['outputHtml']))
    {
     echo "<div class='commentBox'>" . "This is from external PHP" . "</div>";
     echo "<div class='commentBox'>" . "This is also from external PHP" . "</div>";
    }
?>
```

And make the include call in your main file `writephp.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test Php </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="writephp.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="allContent">   
        <?php for($i=0; $i<3; $i++): ?>
            <div class="commentBox">
               <p> Just a box</p>
            </div>  
        <?php endfor; ?>
        <?php include 'write.php'?>
        <a href="writephp.php?outputHtml">Php output</a>       
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

This will include your two new boxes inside the container when you click in the link.

Also you will note that there is nothing special about styling content from an included file, that is because in the end all the markup is rendered as a single HTML page, it doesn't matter if the content is echoed from the main page or the included file, it will obey any rules in your CSS

Comment: Thanks, I learned a little from this answer but it's still not there. My goal is learning php but I am getting stuck with css formmatting. This is just an example of my not understanding how to format html that is coming from external php code.I tried to make up a simple example just outputting some boxes to demonstrate. So my question is still how do I properly do this when the html is from php from an external file.

Comment: @user2250892 what happened?

Comment: @user2250892 can you elaborate on your use case? what are the boxes for? what's the link for?

Comment: I think my main question is "how do I place the echoed output from an external php file any where I want on the page". I see what you mean that what I am doing is placing the output before the `<!doctype>` tag on my page, obviously not good.

Comment: @user2250892 I updated my answer, please take a look and tell me if anything is not clear

Comment: Yes I see how that works now. Although the external html is now added after the closing `</html>` tag. Thanks for all your help, I tried to give you more than one +1 but I can't.

Comment: @user2250892 how come? the content should be included inside #allContent just before the link

Comment: I hadn't implemented your solution entirely, I had only moved the include to before the echo's in the external php file. When I copied your example and then clicked the anchor a new page was shown with just the two echo statements and the comment boxes from the main page were gone. It didn't insert into the page a new page was created.

Comment: @user2250892 make sure the link is pointing to the right file, it should link to your main file not the file with your external boxes, so it's kind of a refresh... you can also try visiting your main page with the ?outputHtml appended in the url so that you see the external code being included

Comment: You forget ";" in <?php include 'write.php'?>. Should be <?php include 'write.php';?>

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not producing the correct content with write.php, probably due to a misunderstanding of what includes actually do.

All the include() function does is take the contents of the included file and parse it as PHP at the point in the file you include it.  It has almost the same effect as cutting and pasting the file contents in the same place.  Only put in your included file what you might type where it is to be put.

I would rewrite the lot properly so that write.php contains only a function that generates a string of html for your commment boxes:

```
<?PHP
function commentbox()
    {
    $output="";
    for($i=0; $i<3; $i++)
    $output.="<div class='commentBox' id='cb_$i'><p> Just a box</p></div>";
    return $output;
    }
?>
```

you include() this at the top of your php file then call its output wherever required by:

```
echo commentbox();
```

or, better:

create a footer.php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test Php </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="writephp.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="allContent">   
        <?PHP echo $content;?>     
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

which you can use with all your projects very easily.

This is used this way:

```
<?PHP
include("write.php");
$content="whatever";
$content.=commentbox();
$content.="whateverelse";
include("footer.php");
?>
```

Even though I have deliberately gone to no trouble to format the above code, it is very easy to find where the content is being created and to debug it.  Mixed PHP and HTML code is a nightmare to debug even with code-context-colouring.  It is also very difficult to find the bit you want to borrow and put somewhere else later.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you shouldn't be using the ID "allContent" on two separate elements. IDs are supposed to be unique. Classes can be used for styling multiple elements.

Why not change it to the code below? Is there a reason you want them to be different?

```
echo '<div class="commentBox"><p>' . 'This is from external PHP' . '</p></div>';  
echo '<div class="commentBox"><p>' . 'This is also from external PHP' . '</p></div>';
```

Comment: I already have `class='commentBox'` there so that they pick up that styling but with that alone they are not  centered; they are not getting the styling from "allContent"